# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 128, 128, 3), found shape=(32, 128, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pre-trained-model

i have the following code portion where i used the vit_b16 model. The input to the model is a 128x128x3 Multi-spectral image.

```
!pip install vit-keras
!pip install tensorflow_addons
from vit_keras import vit, utils
IMG_SIZE = (128,128)
vit_base_model =  vit.vit_b16(image_size=IMG_SIZE,pretrained=True,include_top=False,pretrained_top=False)
vit_model = Model(inputs=vit_base_model.input, outputs=vit_base_model.layers[18].output)
model=keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(vit_model)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(226))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(226))
model.summary()
model.compile(
     optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
     loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), 
     metrics=[keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()],
)
epochs = 20
model.fit(Ref_L7,hyp_patches,epochs=epochs, validation_data=0.1)
```

I am getting this error from the model.compile part.

[image]

hyp_patches.shape=(128,128,262)
Ref_l7.shape=(128,128,3)

Then using PCA i converted the Ref_l7 to 3 bands. Now that is the input we feed into the vit model.

Comment: Please print the shape of ```Ref_L7,hyp_patches``` and edit your question with them

Comment: Ref_l7.shape=(128,128,6) hyp_patches.shape=(128,128,262)

Comment: Yes your sizes are not matching as you can see, ```128x128x3``` this is required but you are passing ```Ref_l7.shape=(128,128,6) hyp_patches.shape=(128,128,262)```. To solve this problem you have to reshape your arrays.

Comment: sorry. The Ref_l7 is actually 128x128x3. 128x128x6 was before using pca. Do i still have to reshape it?

Comment: What is the length of Ref_17?

Comment: You have to reshape the ref_17 to this shape ```(lengthOfRef_17,128,128,3)```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your size of data, and you can try with this, also your shape of data in `fit` should be `(numberofImages,128,128,3)`.

```
IMG_SIZE = (128,128,3)
vit_base_model =  vit.vit_b16(image_size=IMG_SIZE,pretrained=True,include_top=False,pretrained_top=False)
vit_model = Model(inputs=vit_base_model.input, outputs=vit_base_model.layers[18].output)
model=keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(vit_model)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(226))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(226))
model.summary()
model.compile(
     optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
     loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), 
     metrics=[keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()],
)
epochs = 20
model.fit(Ref_L7,hyp_patches,epochs=epochs, validation_data=0.1)
```

Changed the IMAGE_SIZE as channel 3 is added. also print your shape of `Ref_L7,hyp_patches` This will give you more information on what's wrong.

Comment: i am getting value error when i changed the image_size. ValueError: The image_size argument must be a tuple of 2 integers or a single integer. Received: (128, 128, 3)